# How to count outgoing links with Google Analytics in accurate and user friendly way?

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, dom-events

Most resources suggest using `onclick` handler with `trackEvent()` for tracking outgoing links. **BUT this way does not work with all navigation methods!** It won’t work if you click with middle button (except Chrome) or control-click (except Chrome and FF) to open new tab, if you right-click and select new tab or window from context menu or if you drag link to another tab. Is such cases `onclick` is simply not called. You can check it with very simple link:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="alert('GO');">GO</a>
```

Putting JavaScript in `href` attribute breaks the link in all cases when new tab or window is opened.

Putting `onclick` in `span` that looks like a link, will not allow users to decide if they want to open in new tab or not.

Finally, going through a redirect page, which tracks outgoing event, causes problems with back navigation – when users try to go back, they get back to the redirect page and then JS again redirects to the destination page. They need to click back twice … quickly.

**Is there a better way, which would be both accurate and user friendly?**

Comment: http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55527

Comment: @Gerben But this way has exactly the problem that I'm describing in first paragraph. The `onclick` is not invoked if you for instance open a new tab by middle click or from context menu.

Comment: Context menu can't be detected by using JS. So if you want to catch that you need to use the redirect method. To fix the back button problem, redirect using `location.replace` to remove the tracking page from the back-button history.

Comment: @Gerben You are genius! This is exactly what I needed! If You put it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context menu can't be detected by using JS. So if you want to catch that you need to use the redirect method. To fix the back button problem, redirect using `location.replace` to remove the tracking page from the back-button history.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any details about Google Analytics.  In general, to track users' external navigation:

[`<a ping>`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#hyperlink-auditing) is made for this purpose.  If `ping` is not available, fall back to changing the links to go through a redirect page.  Use a 302 redirect to prevent it from showing up in history; if you can't, try `javascript:window.location.replace()`.

Comment: The `ping` thing seems very interesting, but I couldn't find it described in HTML specification on W3C. I've checked with FF with packet capture and it did not make the request as described in the document you linked. It just went to `href` target. Still I would need to fake GA request to log the even, which probably wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @okrasz: `<a ping>` is new feature that is being considered for HTML5.  I know it works in Chrome; I thought it was implemented [in Firefox](http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/darin/archives/009594.html) first, but I don't use it so I'm not sure.

Comment: It would be a yet another very valuable feature of HTML5.  Though I cannot find it in current draft (http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-a-element). Anyhow, currently it wouldn't make "accurate" requirement anyway. Good to know for future if it makes into HTML5. For now the `location.replace` works as charm for me, so I'll leave "aceepted" answer on Gerben, as he first suggested it in comments.